# Reactstrap - how to create dropdown inside a Form Group

Tags: reactjs, dropdown, reactstrap

I'm trying to include a dropdown inside a React form using react-strap. However, there are a number of jolting cosmetic issues.

1. The selections box drops UP instead of down.
2. The dropdown box shows no default value and is therefore very narrow.
3. The dropdown box doesn't align with the rest of the form.

Here is the code in question:

```
   <div class="form-row">
    <ButtonDropdown isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen} toggle={this.toggle}>
        <DropdownToggle caret>
            {this.state.dropDownValue}
        </DropdownToggle>
        <DropdownMenu>
        <DropdownItem onClick={() => this.handleChangeDropdown("Prod A")} dropDownValue="Prod A">Prod A</DropdownItem>
            <DropdownItem onClick={() => this.handleChangeDropdown("Prod B")} dropDownValue="Prod B">Prod B</DropdownItem>
        </DropdownMenu> 

    </ButtonDropdown>

</div>

<div class="form-row">

<div class="form-group col-md-6">
<FormGroup>
    <Label for="fullName">Full Name</Label>
    <Input type="text" name="fullName" id="fullName" value={item.fullName || 
    ''}
           onChange={this.handleChange} autoComplete="fullName"/>
    <span style={{color: "red"}}>{this.state.errors["fullName"]}</span>

  </FormGroup>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <FormGroup>
    <Label for="company">Company</Label>
    <Input type="text" name="company" id="company" value={item.company || 
    ''}
           onChange={this.handleChange} />
  </FormGroup>
  </div>

</div>
...etc
```

Is there any way to make this dropdown box align with the rest of the input fields, drop downwards, and have a default value?

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your `DropdownToggle` component with a `Dropdown` component. Example:

```js
import { Dropdown, DropdownToggle, DropdownItem, DropdownMenu} from "reactstrap";

// other code 

return (
  <Dropdown isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen} toggle={this.toggle}>
    <DropdownToggle caret>{this.state.dropDownValue}</DropdownToggle>
    <DropdownMenu>
      <DropdownItem onClick={() => this.handleChangeDropdown("Prod A")} dropDownValue="Prod A">
        Prod A
      </DropdownItem>
      <DropdownItem onClick={() => this.handleChangeDropdown("Prod B")} dropDownValue="Prod B">
        Prod B
      </DropdownItem>
    </DropdownMenu>
  </Dropdown>
);
```

More about it here
https://reactstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/

Comment: Unfortunately, it makes no difference. I can't find any examples of using react-strap to fill in a field in a form using dropdown.

Comment: The existing dropdown in the sandbox (already there) doesn't do anything. If I paste in the example, it doesn't compile. The example itself that you linked to works from there (the place where the example is at). Also, I can derive the value from the code that I posted and display it in the console. I guess what I need is something that defaults to whatever had been chosen previously, and also one that fits into the input form. I'm having trouble with all that.

Comment: This is the kind of functionality I need https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/